# How to know what type of webservice is being used?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

My project includes a web-service but I have no idea what type. Aside from the files extension of ".svc" which implies WCF is there any other meta data available in VS that relates to the web-service.

And similarly if I have a project in VS is there a way I can know type of project it is? I don't see anything under the properties tab.

Comment: The "type" you're looking for depends on the bindings in use. If you use basicHttpBinding, you've got a SOAP 1.1 service, for example.

Comment: Where can I see the binding?

Answer (score 0):

Xml Web services have a file extension of .asmx in asp.net.

The type of of project can be predicted by the Output Type in  Project Properties
->Application. 
If its C# proj or VB proj, it can be predicted by .csproj or .vbproj extensions respectively of project files.

Or look for XML Tags inside the project's .csproj/.vbproj file. Look for  `<ProjectTypeGuids>` element.This tag holds the type of the project.

Comment: The first part of your answer has nothing to do with the question, which is about WCF, not ASMX.